# Macro double underline range if col q = *

Tags: excel, formatting, underline, vba

I have a question that I cant solve. The problem lies in col Q. What I want is simple:

Scan col Q from row 5 until last row (last row value is in cell "AL1")
If there is a "*" (symbol is stored in cell "AK2") in that row of Q. 
Then double underline cells A thru AF in that row, continue scanning down until last row.

```
    Sub Reformat()

    Dim SrchRng3 As Range
    Dim c3 As Range, f As String

   Set SrchRng3 = ActiveSheet.Range("Q5",          ActiveSheet.Range("Q100000").End(xlUp))
Set c3 = SrchRng3.Find(Range("ak2"), LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not c3 Is Nothing Then
    f = c3.Address
    Do
        With ActiveSheet.Range("A" & c3.Row & ":AF" & c3.Row)
        Range("A" & c3.Row & ":AF" & c3.Row).Select
                .Borders (xlEdgeBottom)
                .LineStyle = xlDouble
                .ThemeColor = 4
                .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
                .Weight = xlThick
        End With
        Set c3 = SrchRng3.FindNext(c3)
    Loop While c3.Address <> f
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying? I have commented the code so you shouldn't have a problem understanding it. If you still do or you get an error, simply let me know :)

```
Sub Reformat()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    '~~> Change as applicable. Do not use Activesheet.
    '~~> The Activesheet may not be the sheet you think
    '~~> is active when the macro runs
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Find last row in Col Q
        lRow = .Range("Q" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Set your Find Range
        Set rng = .Range("Q5:Q" & lRow)

        '~~> Find (When searching for "*" after add "~" before it.
        Set aCell = rng.Find(What:="~" & .Range("AK2"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            Set bCell = aCell

            '~~> Create the necessary border that you are creating
            With .Range("A" & aCell.Row & ":AF" & aCell.Row).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                .LineStyle = xlDouble
                .ThemeColor = 4
                .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
                .Weight = xlThick
            End With

            Do
                Set aCell = rng.FindNext(After:=aCell)

                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                    If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do

                    '~~> Create the necessary border that you are creating
                    With .Range("A" & aCell.Row & ":AF" & aCell.Row).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                        .LineStyle = xlDouble
                        .ThemeColor = 4
                        .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
                        .Weight = xlThick
                    End With
                Else
                   Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me Siddharth. That code is very nice and is almost perfect. the only issue is that it only selects the first "*". The "*" shows up multiple times in col q at random intervals. everything else is perfect. Thanks again and hopefully its just a minor change.

As for the orginal code it was many pieces of many  unsuccessful google searches. Thanks for the tips. I used them in the rest of the macro that this is a part of

Comment: Thank you, the code is now perfect and does exactly.What I want. I'll ask you the same question I did in the other answer that worked. Is there anyway to make this macro always on. so that as soon as the * is typed the underline appears?

Comment: [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640) will get you started. If you are stuck then feel free to ask a new question. Hope I have answered your main query here?

Comment: I added the code found on that link but it doesn't appear to run the code all the time. I dont know if I need to unlink the macro from the button I created or if I need to insert the autrun code and the underline code into a new module. I'll try again in a bit and let you know

Answer (score 1):

The AutoFilter version:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub showSymbol()
    Dim lRow As Long, ur As Range, fr As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet
        lRow = .Range("Q" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set ur = .Range("A5:AF" & lRow)
        Set fr = ur.Offset(1).Resize(ur.Rows.Count - 1)

        ur.Columns(17).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="~" & .Range("AK2").Value2
        fr.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlDouble
        fr.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlDouble
        ur.AutoFilter
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

To execute it for every OnCahange event of one particular sheet add this to its VBA module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .CountLarge = 1 Then 'run only if one cell was updated

            'restrict the call to column Q only, and if the new value is same as cell AK2
            If .Column = 17 And .Value2 = Me.Range("AK2").Value2 Then showSymbol

        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

---

To execute it for all sheets in the file, add this to the VBA module for ThisWorkbook:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.CountLarge = 1 Then If Target.Column = 17 Then showSymbol

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @PaulBica, this option did work almost perfectly and quite rapidly. Thank you for reminding me to use  screenupdating to speed things up. I have many cobwebs on my macro skills, thanks for the code.  


If there are two * in a row sometimes the code doesn't grab the first or the second. Do I need to  modify the offset to correct this?

Also this macro may be run multiple times on the same sheet is there anyway to have this "always running" / as soon as * is placed in Col Q the macro will auto format that row?

Sorry for all the follow ups but I like to make things idiot proof

Comment: I updated the answer to fix the issue you mentioned and to allow it to be "on" all the time - thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I inserted a new module and input the first option you presented and it doesn't seem to be working. I'll try again after my meeting, But again thank you for the help

Comment: `Worksheet_Change()` has to go in the module for the **sheet** (not a new VBA module) - so if you want to update Sheet1, open VBA module for Sheet1 (under "Microsoft Excel Objects", not "Modules")

Comment: That was my problem and again Thanks. The auto update is perfect now. Like I said lots of cobwebs but now this project is idiot proof for the most.

Comment: The auto update works very well, my only issue is I run into an error if I try to clear the data on the page or use my other macro to place data on the page  " runtime error 13 type mismatch "

        Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'restrict the call to column Q only, and if the new value is same as cell AK2

    If Target.Column = 17 And Target.Value2 = Me.Range("AK2").Value2 Then 'this is where the debugger highlights
        'showSymbol code
    
End If

End Sub

Comment: I updated the last 2 subs to execute only when you edit one cell. Replace `Worksheet_Change()` with the latest one and try clearing the data on the page (or placing data on it)